# Leer csv en Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, csv

Al intentar leer un archivo csv con un header y dos filas en python con el código:

`df_csv = pd.read_csv('csv.csv', delimiter=',')`

sólo me separa bien los datos de la primera fila, dejandome los de la segunda juntos en la primera columna de la segunda fila y no consigo ver por qué.

¿ Qué se me está pasando?

Gracias

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar los datos a tu pregunta? Así sin ver es muy difícil adivinar lo que pasa

Comment: Hola Victor! Como dice @HeytalePazguato, si puedes añadir los datos, no solo será más visual y fácil para nosotros, si no que también podremos crear el `.csv` con tus mismos datos y poder ver mejor por qué no funciona!